# Jquery Toggle Function - Trigger/Button After Revelaed Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I've been struggling with this and I'm sure there must be a simple solution! I have a simple button that triggers a Jquery toggle reveal/hide which is working fine:

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
 //hide the all of the element with class msg_body
  $(".reveal-info-1").hide();
  //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
   $(".reveal-btn").click(function(){
    $(this).next(".reveal-info-1").slideToggle(500);
   });
  });
</script>
```

My HTML looks something like this (there's a lot of content so I've simplified it):

```
<div class="reveal-1">
 <div class="reveal-btn"><input type="button" value="Read More" id="reveal-btn-1" class="reveal-btn" /></div>
 <div class="reveal-info-1">
  <p>Content goes here</p>
 </div
</div>
```

What I need is for the button/trigger to appear after the revealed content. Moving the button seems to break things so I guess in the flow of the code it has to appear before the toggled content? Is there anyway of achieving this without some nasty CSS hacks?

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Moving the button seems to break things so I guess in the flow of the code it has to appear before the toggled content?

This is only happening because you're using jQuery `.next`, which looks for the next adjacent HTML element.

Change the order and alter that line to `.prev`, and it'll be fixed:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //hide the all of the element with class msg_body
  $(".reveal-info-1").hide();
  //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
  $(".reveal-btn").click(function() {
    $(this).prev(".reveal-info-1").slideToggle(500);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="reveal-1">
  <div class="reveal-info-1">
    <p>Content goes here</p>
  </div>
  <div class="reveal-btn"><input type="button" value="Read More" id="reveal-btn-1" class="reveal-btn" /></div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you don't need to use `prev` or `next` - you could simply address that element by its selector alone (like you do when hiding it on load):

`$(".reveal-info-1").slideToggle(500);`

Comment: That's great, many thanks for your help, swapping "next" with "prev" works perfectly after swapping the code around (removing all references to "prev" and "next" doesn't seem to keep the revelaed div open (it just expands and contracts)).